# Netty channel close

Tags: java, netty, nio

I hava a question about Netty channel.

I inserted a channel handler into a channel pipeline. When connection is down (for example, the peer socket closed), **channelInactive** method is called:

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {

}
```

Do I need to explicitly close the channel in **channelInactive** method? like:

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.channel().close();
}
```

Does Netty do some cleanup for me? Or I have to do some cleanup myself?

Comment: what did you mean with "cleanup" ? or what are you expecting in this cleanup?

Comment: @Hector I mean close the channel(socket) to release memory.

Comment: I assume netty cleanups by itself, because none of the examples use .close() in their handlers, but this is not a good proof